# dbt: Using 'this' function has different results in compile/preview vs dbt run

Tags: dbt

When using the DBT web IDE, I'm seeing different behavior in the `{{ this }}` function when I use preview or compile as opposed to building the model with `dbt run`. When I use preview or compile, the model name is always `request`, but when I build the model with `dbt run`, it correctly resolves the model name.

For example, in `my_model.sql`:

```
{{ this.database }}
{{ this.schema }}
{{ this.name }}

dev_db
public
request
```

If I run `dbt run -s my_model`, in the details of the run I see:

```
dev_db
public
my_model
```

My question is how can I get the behavior of preview/compile to match that of `dbt run`? I would like `{{ this.name }}` to correctly resolve to `my_model`.

Answer (score 1):

I think when you hit 'compile' or 'run' in the IDE, it just takes the contents of your editor window and compiles or compiles/runs it, independent of the file itself. In some cases this makes sense, eg I can start a new tab and 'run' it without saving it as a file.

Because of this, it seems like it's getting the temporary name `request` rather than the name of the model.

I don't know if dbt Labs would consider this a bug, likely more it's by design, but speaking to their support is probably your best next step.